# Porting a Rails 1.2 app, schema.rb generation messed up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

rake db:schema:dump
rake db:test:prepare

All use the following generated schema.rb:

t.column "cost_per_license", :decimal, :limit => 8, :default => #

Running rake db:migrate does not cause this problem as it only uses the migration files (and not the resulting schema.rb)

Has anyone seen this in Rails 1.2?  The following lines are generating this schema:

126_create_accounts.rb:      t.column :cost_per_license, :decimal, :precision => 8, :scale => 2, :default => 0

I have tried Ruby 1.8.6, 1.8.7, and Rails 1.2.1, and 1.2.6 -- all schema.rb's generated have this same syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

There was a vendor/plugin (specifically spatial_adapter) that was monkey patching the SchemaDumper's table() function with a terribly old version of ActiveRecord's table() (either really old, or just really awful.)

Comment: Thanks so much for posting this reply! This was fixed here: https://github.com/fragility/spatial_adapter/commit/1452247eace22e79a4e3785140dbb8b0dff32fe4

Answer (score 1):

If you have a problem with the schema.rb produced, one hack is you can override module ActiveRecord class SchemaDumper and the method that is producing the particular line and just replace ':default => #' with ':default => 0'

for the root cause can you do a show create table on the particular table (if you are using mysql)?  and is it dong that for all columns with a default value or just that cost_per_license one?